# vue-router not pushing while inside a store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

This is my `store`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import router from '@/main';
import mainStore from './modules/main-store';
import loginStore from './modules/login-store';

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        mainStore,
        loginStore
    }
});
```

and my `login-store.js`

```js
//other imports
import router from '@/main';

const actions = {
 forceLogout(){
    localStorage.removeItem('token')
    localStorage.removeItem('user')
    delete API.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']
    router.push('/login')
  },
 //other actions
}
```

And my `router.js`:

```js
import store from './stores'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
    mode: 'hash',
    routes: [
     {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: Login,
     },
  ]
  //other routes
})
//... some router.afterEach and router.beforeEach

export default router
```

There is a case where I need the `store` to force a logout and this is how I do it, I call the `forceLogout` action from a file named `api.js`

```js
import store from './../stores';

//....
if(error_msg == 'Not_Logged'){
  store.dispatch('forceLogout')
}
//....
```

I've tried changing an import:

```js
import router from 'vue-router'
//...
router.push('/login')
```

Same thing with importing

```js
import router from '@/main'
router.push('/login')
```

and I keep on getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: What is your router.js file looks like? Are you importing router.js?

Comment: @onuriltan, ok I made some edits, can you pls review?

Comment: Import router from `router.js`

Comment: I think you should import router like this: `import router from '@/router' `

Comment: I tried `import router from '@/router'` and does not return any error but does not go to the page. Is it because the mode is `"mode: 'hash'"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you're exporting your router.

`router.js` should include `export default router` so then when you `import router from '@/main'` it actually imports something.

Comment: Because after `const router = new Router({...})` I have some `router.afterEach(...)` and `router.beforeEach(...)` I export it at the end of the file with `export default router`. I've added it in the original question

Comment: As @onuriltan said, the import is definitelly `import router from '@/router'` as you need to point to your router.js file. But we'd need a minimal reproduction on https://codesandbox.io or whatever in order is see any issue.